# Spark type mismatch error - found : Any but required: List

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm facing issue with auto casting from array to any.

```
scala> val selectedFieldsDF = dfFinal.select("id","attributes");
scala> selectedFieldsDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- attributes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Right now dataframe has only one record:

```
scala> selectedFieldsDF.show(20, false)
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id|attributes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1425942469761    |[Map(attribute_value -> Bordspellen, column_id -> 2958, attribute_name -> CAT level 2:Soort gezelschapsspellen), Map(attribute_value -> Gezelschapsspellen, column_id -> 2956, attribute_name -> CAT level 1:Soort), Map(attribute_value -> Spelshop.be, column_id -> 47, attribute_name -> Winkel)]|
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Defined allItems class:

```
scala> case class allItems(id: Long, attr: List[Map[String,String]], valid: Boolean)
    defined class allItems
```

selectedFieldsDF transforming to another df using case class  allItems

But I am facing    type mismatch issue as shown below even though item(1) is List[Map[String,String]](you can see schema above)

```
scala> val allPreItemsDF = selectedFieldsDF.rdd.map({item=> allItems(toLong(item(0).toString),item(1),true)
     | })
<console>:36: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: List[Map[String,String]]
       val allPreItemsDF = selectedFieldsDF.rdd.map({item=> allItems(toLong(item(0).toString),item(1),true)
                                                                                                  ^
```

Comment: Can you paste in some of the first dataframe's rows?

Comment: @shakedzy  pasted row of dataframe, please check it

Comment: @user8371915 Thank you for reference link, I see simple  data types in that question but in my case it is complex data type and I don't know what I have to use instead of getInt, getLong methods.

Comment: `getAs[Seq[Map[String,String]]]` or `getSeq[Map[String,String]]`

Comment: `item(0)`, `item(1)` etc are all of type `Any`, use `getAs[T](0)` etc instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
selectedFieldsDF.rdd.map({item=> allItems(item.getLong(0),item.getAs[List[Map[String,String]]](1),true)})
```

Use Spark's built-in field conversion methods

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you so much.